# How do i change the type of a colume of a dataframe in a list in R

Tags: r, excel, import, bind-rows

I imported some cleaned excel datas into R

```
files <- list.files(pattern=".xlsx")
files
combined_2023 <- setNames(lapply(files, read.xlsx), files)
```

Then i proceeded to combining the rows of the list using bind_rows
`combined_23 <- bind_rows(combined_2023)`
I got the error

```
! Can't combine `..1$ride_length` <double> and `..7$ride_length` <character>.
```

checked and found out one of the ride length is formatted as character instead of double been trying to fix to no avail. I am a newbie

[image]

I tried formatting the file as "time" in excel as i did to all other ride_length column of other data frames in the list but only that particular one still shows "chr"

Comment: FYI: If you used `sapply` with `simplify=FALSE` instead of `lapply`, you do not need `setNames`.

Comment: Something in the `ride_length` column of one of your files is not number-like, so R reads in the whole column as string. To find what the problem values are in the `i`th file, perhaps something like `head(grep("^[-+]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*$", combined[[i]]$ride_length, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE))`.

Comment: Why don't you format `ride_length` column in that particularly excel as number instead of `time` since other are `double`?

Comment: @Jinjin I formattted the `ride_length` column of all the files in the list as `time` but i dont know why it is registering the `ride_length` of the 6th file as `chr` instead of `num` it recognised others as.

Comment: @r2evans I don't understand what it means, but I tried it: `head(grep("^[-+]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*$", combined_2023[["2023_06-cyclistic_tripdata.xlsx"]]$ride_length, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE))` and I got feedback.                                                        `[1] "9.3981481481481485E-3" "2.4074074074074076E-3" "5.185185185185185E-3" 
[4] "5.115740740740741E-3"  "1.3078703703703705E-3" "4.9305555555555552E-3"`

Comment: I also just tried formatting the ride_length column in the 6th file as numeric in R using  `combined_2023[["2023_06-cyclistic_tripdata.xlsx"]] <- mutate(combined_2023[["2023_06-cyclistic_tripdata.xlsx"]],
                   ride_length = as.numeric(ride_length))`     I got this warning  `Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
ℹ In argument: `ride_length = as.numeric(ride_length)`.
Caused by warning:
! NAs introduced by coercion `  but upon checking the structure it has changed to `num`

Comment: I think you want to bind columns and not by rows.  “Bind_rows” will give you 2 columns and 500000 rows.

Comment: Clearly we need a better regex to find where the problem is in your days. Or you can look at it all yourself and find something that is not a number. Try something like `z <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(combined[[i]]$ride_length)); head(combined[[i]]$ride_length[is.na(z)])` (untested).

Comment: Form what you are showing, it looks like your read.xlsx function cannot read numbers in scientific notation. You can manually convert column ride_length to numeric, e.g. df$ride_length = as.numeric(df$ride_length). Alternatively, you can check if your read.xlsx function has any arguments that can be used to read scientific notation correctly. Or you can look for a better function to read Excel, such as read_excel in the readxl package.